# Most suitable table representation in c++?

Tags: c++, database, boost

I need to represent a table in c++ frequently. For example, in an application I need to maintain a table as follows.

```
int analog_channel;
int operator_channel;
state channel_state;
string phone_number;
```

But I need to make `analog_channel` and `operator_channel` indexable. What's the most suitable table representation in c++ for this kind of data, `boost_multiindex`or something else?

Comment: why not store the data in a database? you can use SQLite, MySQL or even the classic MS Access DB.. MySQL for instance provides indexable columns and is incredibly fast if you learn how to use it

Comment: I need to represent the table in memory.

Comment: ok in that case i see no problem with boost_multiindex, i am not sure if there are better libraries for this specific task, STL seems a good choice too

Comment: whether there is a boost_multiindex alternative in qt?

Comment: i would classify the libs like so Boost > STL > QT (with Boost being the best) so i say stay away from qT, it's more a GUI library if you ask me

Comment: You can use sqlite entirely in-memory, if you really want. But the whole point of a database is that you really don't have to care whether it's in-memory or on-disk; with the default settings, you'll still get very good performance on small databases, and won't run out of memory/thrash your VM on large databases (plus, you'll get persistence, CRUD, etc. for free). Still, if you explicitly don't want that for some reason, boost_multiindex is pretty nice.

Comment: I wanna to use database and the the table is to be inserted to database, but i need to gather the information of the table before i insert it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[boost::multi_index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) would be a good choice.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried qT ? It has some of boost's features i think but that's what i use and it's cute :D

http://qt.nokia.com/products/

You can check the list of features on that site for details on each class...

Comment: None of [Qt's containers](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/containers.html) provide multiple indexes.